# How to make a message box always ready to enter text that are being typed

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, user-input

For example ,Some message box are prompt to enter message. means if I type a message and hit enter it will be ready again to type next one.

[image: boxtype1]

But some message box after typing the message and sending,asks to click on the box again so that the cursor appears there and then you will be able to type

[image: boxtype2].

I don't want to use mouse or touchpad to click on the box again and then type. Is there any way like tempermonkey script or any inspect element tip or any chrome extension that can help? I want to do it from user side ,that is not my website.I face problem when messaging ,I am not a developer and don't know anything about programming languages yet.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Simply edit the question and add the code, select it, then press the `{}` button or Ctrl-K.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't know about coding,I need any extension or script to help me

Comment: Well, you have another problem then. StackOverflow is a learning tool for programmers who ask for help with programming, not a platform to post software requests. There must be certainly some other forums.

Comment: I asked it on super user first ,they said it is for stack overflow